# How to enable the close window button here?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

My GUI looks like this and I want to enable to closing button of the window which currently does nothing when clicked:

[image]

The JSP is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" class="TB_nb">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök person/företag</h2> 
</td>
  <td align="right">X</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<h2 class="pusher">Sök person/företag</h2>
<div id="Vsok">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='none'" class="link_sm">Visa s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

</div>

<div id="sokF">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display=''" class="link_sm">D&ouml;lj s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;" class="fontS80">
<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Fysisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchFornamn"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Efternamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Juridisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;retag:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Organisationsnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
</fieldset> <br><br>


<div class="fl30">Postort:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Land:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="2">&nbsp;
                    <select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl50">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fl5"><input type="button" value="Rensa"></div>
<div class="fl10"><input type="button" value="  S&ouml;k  " onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</div>
<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tr>    
    <td><h3>Sökresultat:</h3></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="4">En massa text <span class="link">Hj&auml;lp!</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td><input type="button" value="Visa alla"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="smallb">
    <td>Antal &auml;renden: 527</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Visa &auml;renden: << 1-200 201-400 401-527 >> </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="sortable" id="unique_id">
<tr>
    <th class="thkant">F&ouml;rnamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Efternamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Adress</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postnr</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postort</th>
    <th class="thkant">Region</th>
    <th class="thkant">Land</th>
    <th class="thkant">Telefonnummer</th>
</tr>

<%
    for(int i=0; i<apc.getSessionData().getNamnsokningLista().size(); i++) {

        PersonInfo person = (PersonInfo)apc.getSessionData().getNamnsokningLista().get(i);
        if(i%2==0) {
%>
<tr class="g1" onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editSearchPerson', '', '<%= person.getPersonId() %>')" style="cursor:pointer;">
<%
        } else {
%>
<tr class="g2"onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editSearchPerson', '', '<%= person.getPersonId() %>')" style="cursor:pointer;">
<%
        } 
%>
    <td><%= person.getFornamn() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getEfternamn() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostadress() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostnr() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostort() %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= person.getLandKod() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getTelefon() %></td> 
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>


<div id="bottomV">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" id="visaknapp" value="Visa" disabled style="width:150px;" onClick="getElementById('sokR').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='none', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='', getElementById('sokF').style.display='none'"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" disabled style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="bottomA" style="display: none">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" value="&Auml;ndra i register" style="width:150px;"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me how to enable the closing function? Thank you

Comment: What is it a fancy box? What do you want to close?

Comment: That's not a closing button, it's an X in a `<td>` element...

Comment: It is a box and I was given the window which can be opened by a JSP include tag so I supposse it's not a "normal" popup, it is inline and therefore has some special rule for how to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what it is exactly what you want to close, but I can show you how to attach an onclick handler to your X:

```
function xOnclick() {
    window.close()
}

<td onclick="xOnclick()" style="text-align: right; cursor: pointer;">X</td>
```

As this code is now, it closes the window, but you could replace it with something else if you need to.

Comment: that's why I asked the OP what it is exactly he wants to close.

Comment: THanks for the answer. I believe it is an inline window since it is opened by JSP include. Then I don't know exactly how to make it close and render the page like it was before the search page was opened.

Comment: well, if you surround the JSP include with a div, give that div an id, you should be able to remove it from your onclick handler.